# How to have secure https without everyone downloading the certificate authority?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm new to web development, and I want to switch my site from http to https. When I generate my keys and use them, the browser (google chrome) said that the https is broken. the solution that I found is to install the certificate into the browser.  the issue with this is that every user has to download the certificate authority into their browser to access my site without having a broken https connection. how do I have a secure https without having the user to download the certificate?

Edit: I forgot to mention this, but I'm using self-signed certificate.

Comment: Are you using your own CA or self-signed certificate? If so, you need to get a certificate from a certificate authority that is already in the trust store (Let's Encrypt, DigiCert, etc).

Comment: @vcsjones I'm using self-signed certificate

Comment: There is no way to get around this with a self signed certificate. You need to get a certificate from a certificate authority that is already in the browser's root trust store.

Comment: Just set up LetsEncrypt with certbot. It's free, it renews your certificate, and browsers already trust it.

Comment: @vcsjones I did not know that, thanks for telling me.

Comment: @cubrr thanks for letting me know about that site.